# How to draw a graph in grafana for json logs from Loki?

Tags: json, logging, grafana-loki

I just want to use the  LOGQL to plot the temperature values.

I tried:
I am able to use |json format and bring the temperature label. But unable to find any LOG QL that will plot this label. Only aggregate functions are there such as count over time.

Logs are stored in the following format:

```
{Temperature":32, "Humidity":42}
{Temperature":31, "Humidity":42}
{Temperature":32, "Humidity":42}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert here, but this is what i figured out in the past days:

You probably don't want `Temperature` to be a label, it can stay in the log line. In the LogQL you can parse it out and plot in Grafana.

Another problem, i think, is that these log lines are bound to single points in time, but Grafana wants data for intervals. So you need an aggregate function.

```
avg_over_time({} |= "Temperature" | json | unwrap Temperature [2m])
```

The `|= "Temperature` part is there to filter out any log events which do not have a temperature field, this is just a search on the log line string, so it won't work if "Temperature" comes up somewhere else.

`[2m] assumes there is usually at least one log line within a 2 minute interval, and so we average all values within that interval.

If Grafana now shows a lot of data series, you want to add sth like  `by (model, id)` (or  `by ()` in your case) to the query to merge them.